# Guardar formularios relacionados Django

Tags: django, formularios

En un principio quería hacer un formulario dinámico en Django, pero encontré que es imposible usando sólo Django ... por lo que ahora decidí crear varios formularios desde su propio Form y renderizarlos en templates distintos pero consecutivos, mi pregunta es cómo puedo guardar la relación de dichos formularios usando Clase Based Views. Tengo lo siguiente:

Models.py

```
class Url_activity (models.Model):
    url_de_la_actividad = models.URLField()
    nombre_url = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    lastModification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url_de_la_actividad

class ActivityProposed (models.Model):
    nombre_actividad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fullname_profesor = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    detalle_de_la_actividad = models.TextField()
    metodologia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foreing_competence = models.ForeignKey(CompetenceProposed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    foreign_url = models.ForeignKey(Url_activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    foreign_comment = models.ForeignKey(CommentsActivityProposed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre_del_curso = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    lastModification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    foreing_activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_actividad
```

forms.py

```
class ActivityProposedForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            metodologias_choices = [(metodologia.id, metodologia.methodology_name) for metodologia in Methodology.objects.all()]
            normas_choices = [(normas.id, normas.norm_name) for normas in Norm.objects.all()]

            model = ActivityProposed

            fields = [
                'nombre_actividad', 'detalle_de_la_actividad', 'metodologia', 
                'nombre_del_curso']

            labels = {
                'nombre_actividad': 'Nombre de la Actividad',
                'detalle_de_la_actividad': 'Detalle de la Actividad',
                'metodologia': 'Metodologia',
                'nombre_del_curso': 'Nombre del Curso'
            }

            widgets = {
                'nombre_actividad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'detalle_de_la_actividad': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3'}),
                'metodologia': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}, choices=metodologias_choices),
                'nombre_del_curso': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            }



class ActivityUrl_activity(forms.ModelForm):

       class Meta:
        model = Url_activity
        fields = (
            'url_de_la_actividad', 'nombre_url')

        labels = {
            'url_de_la_actividad': 'URL de la Actividad',
            'nombre_url': 'Nombre del Boton a la URL'
        }

        widgets = {
            'url_de_la_actividad': forms.URLInput(),
            'nombre_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

views.py

```
class CreateActivityProposed(CreateView):
    template_name = 'registerActivity.html'
    form_class = ActivityProposedForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('actividades:createurl')

class CreateURLProposed(CreateView):
    template_name = 'urlForm.html'
    form_class = ActivityUrl_activity
```

alguna idea?
Saludos!!!

Comment: has leído acerca de los formsets? creo que pudiera ayudarte para lo que quieres https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

Añade `foreign_url` a los fields de `ActivityProposeForm` con esto Django te renderizara el template y te mostrara una lista deplegable con los `Url_activity` que tengas disponible y al guardar el form Django los relaciona.

Debe de quedarte más o menos asi:

```
class ActivityProposedForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        metodologias_choices = [(metodologia.id, metodologia.methodology_name) for metodologia in Methodology.objects.all()]
        normas_choices = [(normas.id, normas.norm_name) for normas in Norm.objects.all()]

        model = ActivityProposed

        fields = [
            'nombre_actividad', 'foreign_url', 'detalle_de_la_actividad', 'metodologia', 
            'nombre_del_curso']

        labels = {
            'nombre_actividad': 'Nombre de la Actividad',
            'detalle_de_la_actividad': 'Detalle de la Actividad',
            'metodologia': 'Metodologia',
            'nombre_del_curso': 'Nombre del Curso'
        }

        widgets = {
            'nombre_actividad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'detalle_de_la_actividad': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '3'}),
            'metodologia': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'}, choices=metodologias_choices),
            'nombre_del_curso': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```